# Ionic 2 RC1 Issue: Content in assets folder not copied in Device run

Tags: ionic2

When doing `ionic run android` and the assets folder is not getting copied to device.
In my case i have translation-files for ng2-translate in src/assets/i18n

When I do `ionic serve`, it all works well in browser, but not happening with Device.

Screenshot of

- Resources tab of Chrome Dev tools
- www/assets that is copied right from src
  [image]

I followed this link https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1761
and did `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@beta`

My Ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:  
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.2
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.36
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.6
Xcode version: Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you solve the problem??

Comment: Not yet. Waiting for the github issue to be resolved

Comment: Hi @saiy2k, the github link given in your thread is out of order. To make sure we talk about the same thing: **Your problem is that what you edit in [your project]\src\assets\i18n\[language initials].json don't get reflected in [your project]\www\assets\i18n\[language initials].json, correct?** And you end up modifying [your project]\www\assets\i18n\[language initials].json to have it working. In my case it is disfunctionning the same with `ionic serve` and `ionic run android`. Any updates?

Comment: Hi @nyluje. My problem was the `i18n*.json` was not getting copied in android build. But now with RC4 upgrade, It's all working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Ionic RC4 and corresponding ionic-app-scripts Upgrade, this issue is resolved.